# Mule: getting a hold of the exception message

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have a default catch exception in Mule, and I'm trying to get access to the exception message, using a Mule expression: #[exception]

This doesn't seem to work, and I'm guessing that I'm trying to access the wrong variable? I'm trying to log it using logger and also run a custom component that takes in an exception message (as a string.)

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share the error message from logs

Comment: After some time I figured out that my issue was due to nesting #[] where they shouldn't have been nested.
However I still have an issue, #[exception] will return the Mule top error, which isn't very interesting in what really happened. I'm just getting invoking a component failed, while the real error I want to output is the root error (permission denied on a directory creation from sftp.) Any way to get the root error message from the #[exception] object?

Comment: #[exception.getCause()] actually gets me what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `#[exception.causedBy]` like

```
   <choice-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(com.company.BusinessException)"> <!-- [1] -->
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="dead.letter">
                <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
            </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <rollback-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(com.company.NonBusinessException)"> <!-- [2] -->
            <logger level="ERROR" message="Payload failing: #[payload]"/>
        </rollback-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

More details [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Exception+Strategy+Most+Common+Use+Cases)

Answer (score 9):

In some cases the `exception.cause` could be `null`, hence advised to use the conditional to display the message:

```
[(exception.cause!=null)?(exception.cause.message):exception]
```

This will prevent **null pointer exception**.

Answer (score 9):

Best way to get exception message (null safe) is :

`#[exception.cause.?message or exception.cause]`

Comment: Hi @Nirmal- thInk beYond.  What is the question mark for in your answer?  What does it do?  Thanks!

---Edit---
Never mind!  I just found the answer here.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-expression-language-tips

Thanks!

Comment: @Rashiki the question mark is a check for a  null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

Hi if you want to get the exception message using MEL you can also (in a Catch Exception Strategy) use the following expression.

```
#[exception.cause.message]
```

Answer (score 1):

exception.cause could be null so it could be handled like this:

```
#[exception.?cause.message or exception]
```